# Subscribe - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a file where I code my whole connection with the REST service, and it works.

From another file, I am executing the following lines (**everything works**)

```
 this.baseService.getCars(ID)
    .subscribe(cars=> this.cars= cars);
```

To access to the values of the response I was using `HTML`. For example: `*ngIf="cars"`

Now, I would like to access by `Javascript` to the variable doing this:

```
this.baseService.getCars(ID)
        .subscribe(cars=> this.cars= cars);
console.log(this.cars)
```

but I get `undefined` but I can access by `HTML`. I know that it is a stu**d question, but how should I do it? Which variable does contain the variable?

Comment: The correct answer is below, but just so you understand, you are not seeing a value for this.cars because you are printing the result before the subscribe is finished.

Comment: I could not check the answer as correct before than 10 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution order of those lines of code is not what you think it is.

To see cars in console, change your function to this:

```
this.baseService.getCars(ID)
        .subscribe(cars=>{ 
    this.cars= cars;
    console.log(this.cars);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying that but I forgot "{}"

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the console.log inside **subscribe**

```
  this.baseService.getCars(ID)
  .subscribe(
    cars=> {
      this.cars= cars;
      console.log(this.cars);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe is asynchronous, like a Promise, but isn't a Promise so, when you execute the code, the subscribe is fired, then the console log. But When the console.log is executing, subscribe is running yet, so that's why you get undefined.

You can do the console.log inside the callback function in subscribe

```
this.baseService
    .getCars(ID)
    .subscribe(cars=> {
        this.cars = cars
        console.log(this.cars)
    });
```

Another solution is to use async/await. You can't use async/await directly with subscribe, because IT'S NOT A PROMISE. Fortunately Observers can be converted to a Promise.

So, in you service you can return a promise, like this:

```
getCars() {
    // your service stuff
    return this.api.get(url).toPromise().then( res => res.data); // This is the important part.
}
```

Then, in your component, call it with async/await:

```
async yourFunction() {
    this.cars = await this.baseService.getCars(ID);
    console.log(this.cars);
}
```

Now you can log `this.cars` after the `getCars()`

Hope this helps you.